# How to insert blend files into a question

Tags: discussion

I wanna ask a question about something concerning parenting in blender but I know I’d be clear if I knew how to insert blend or .mov files into my question. How do you do that on Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this tool to post a blend file into a question https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thanks!........

Comment: Could you flag this as answer if it helped you?

Comment: How do u do that?

Comment: Click the grey check mark on the left below the up/down vote buttons and it becomes green.

Comment: I wanted to mark this Q as duplication, but I really can't find any. Every second question here use blend-exchange link in Question's comment. There is something wrong in a system. Seems to be still very hard discoverable ....hm